# Walk/Run from Berlin Tegel Airport to Berlin City Centre

Tags: airports, berlin, walking

I am visiting Berlin in May for a short weekend trip (hand luggage only). I see that it's only 11km from the airport to the city centre. I wondered if it is possible to run/walk from the airport into the city on pavements/footpaths and not get caught out having to run on roads at all?
I am taking running kit anyway so it's a good use of time if possible and a nice way to see part of the city.
Thanks

Comment: Usually people ask for public transport or taxi. +1 For the courage!

Comment: I understand that there are many other reasons than cost for walking to the city center, but 
I'd like to mention that in Berlin there is no additional rip-off fare for buses going to/from the airport, unlike many other cities. A single ticket from Tegel to anywhere in the city center costs the same as a normal bus ticket (which is 2.70E for a single ride, at the moment when I am writing this).

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Other cities in Europe have a modern airport with a fast train link to the center. Berlin has neither (but a massive failure of the plan to build just that) so it seems only fair that the bus would be cheap ;-)

Comment: @Relaxed Berlin does have a shiny modern new airport with fast train links to the centre though! Not one that's open mind you, but it does exist, unhelpful though that is...

Comment: @relaxed there is the RE7 (Airport Express) running from Schönefeld to the city in ~20 min. There is also the TXL running every 5 min. and takes ~20 min. to the Hauptbahnhof. No need for a trainlink or an bigger airport. Public transportation in Berlin is indeed very good.

Comment: @ectomorph We are talking about Tegel here and it is only served by busses. And yes there is a need for a bigger airport (or at least a modern functional one), Tegel is quirky and nice once in a while but it's not up to the task and was supposed to close several years ago. Schönefeld feels like a hangar and the train station like a derelict suburban station. I am not saying that to disparage the city, I know Berlin very well, lived there for some time and loved it. But seriously you can't compare Tegel and Schönefeld to major European airports…

Comment: @Gagravarr Yes, that's the “massive failure of a plan” I was talking about. OK, it's a little more than a plan now but still a massive failure and won't be a functional airport for at least a few more years. On the flip side, the worries that it would open before the train link was fully ready do not seem very important anymore ;-)

Comment: Also, comparing like with like €2.70 for a trip within the city center (which this is) isn't particularly cheap. It's €1.80 in Paris. On the other hand it's true that the Berlin ABC ticket is extremely good value, airport or no airport.

Comment: @Relaxed: You mentioned Berlin in your comment not Tegel. But the buses serving it very well. Both airports are working efficiently and are capable to manage the traffic so there is no need to bury billions. The Berlin hype will decrease and we are not a city comparable to London, Paris or Moscow. It's just Berlin with all it's modesty, space and contentment - the whole city feels like a hangar sometimes. That's the spirit of Berlin and the reason why all the Hipsters come here to claim it.

Comment: @ectomorph The question and the comment I am reacting to are exclusively about Tegel… And seriously, even if Berlin truly is smaller/less important, Tegel is completely overloaded, with increasing noise nuisance right in the middle of a city that actually has a lot more space available than most (you do know there was a court order to close the airport several years back, right?). On top of that, Berlin managed something other cities haven't: It already did bury the millions but it doesn't have a functional airport to show for it…

Comment: @Relaxed: I think you are wrong in some points but obviously we're off topic at this point.

Comment: FYI, https://github.com/monperrus/airport-by-foot/ is about this topic :-)

Answer (score 30):

I am living in Berlin Moabit which is very close to Tegel Airport. Since Tegel and Moabit are not that interesting at the first sight (which is what you catch when running I think), you should take the TXL-Bus (public transport / 2.8€) running every 10 min. from the airport to the inner city. Then you should jump off at U-Bhf Turmstraße (subwaystation) and run along the Spree river. You can then choose three different options (assuming you want to reach U-/S-Bhf Friedrichstraße):

1. Just run along the river (dark red)
2. Take a small turn to see the [Reichstag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reichstag_building), the [Brandenburger Tor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brandenburg_Gate)  and the [Kanzleramt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_Chancellery)(where Merkel hangs around) (red)
3. Take a bigger turn to see the [Siegessäule](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berliner_Siegess%C3%A4ule), the [Reichstag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reichstag_building) and the [Brandenburger Tor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brandenburg_Gate). You could also stop/pass at the [Memorial for the Murdered Jews](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memorial_to_the_Murdered_Jews_of_Europe). (green)

I added a map to show these three options which I consider the most "impressive". I would suggest to take option three (green).

[image]

Some useful links:

- [Map of the airport / how to find the bus station](http://www.berlin-airport.de/en/travellers-txl/to-and-from/buses-and-trains/how-to-get-there/index.php)
- [Subwaymap of Berlin](http://www.berlin-airport.de/de/_dokumente/reisende/2015-01-16-vbb-liniennetz-berlin.pdf)
- [BVG - public transportation authority of Berlin](http://www.bvg.de/en/)

Comment: Based on the number of up-votes you've received, you ought to now have enough reputation to be able to provide more links!

Comment: @Grgravarr: thx - just added some links :)

Answer (score 15):

Google maps says [yes](https://www.google.be/maps/dir/art%27otel+berlin+city+center+west+by+park+plaza,+Lietzenburger+Stra%C3%9Fe+85,+10719+Berlin,+Germany/Berlin+Tegel+Airport,+Flughafen+Tegel,+13405+Berlin,+Germany/@52.5292229,13.2320566,12z/data=!4m14!4m13!1m5!1m1!1s0x47a850faf5b4f0d1:0xc7b6b4e133eccddd!2m2!1d13.322622!2d52.499667!1m5!1m1!1s0x47a853f955555555:0x64b97d7d67bf2aea!2m2!1d13.288437!2d52.558833!3e2?hl=en). I have done it once (walking, not running) and I didn't like the first part. I would recommend taking any bus into the city and getting out 2 or 3 stops from the airport.

Answer (score 9):

Andra is right. It's possible, but the nearest vicinity of the airport is rather dull. Better take a bus for some stops.

If you want to walk the whole distance, maybe [head a bit east first, then south](https://www.google.be/maps/dir/52.5162906,13.3770278/Berlin+Tegel+Airport,+Flughafen+Tegel,+13405+Berlin,+Germany/@52.5369501,13.3298178,13z/data=!4m19!4m18!1m10!3m4!1m2!1d13.3501974!2d52.5151558!3s0x47a851af369fdb35:0xe06c6cf6f20d3db4!3m4!1m2!1d13.3261781!2d52.5389962!3s0x47a8516859bf393f:0xc9814e14d672b7d6!1m5!1m1!1s0x47a853f955555555:0x64b97d7d67bf2aea!2m2!1d13.288437!2d52.558833!3e2?hl=en). As soon as you reach Moabit (around Beusselstr station) the walk is becoming more interesting.

Answer (score 6):

If you like walking or running, you will be very pleased to hear that unless
walking is explicitly forbidden ("Kein Zutritt", "Privatgelände", no walking on Autobahns. please), you may walk or run everywhere in Germany and you will be able to reach
practically every location by walking/running.
As the others already said, the road is really, really boring, but if you don't mind....

Comment: "until"? "unless"?

Comment: yeah...corrected...